# how to have full rank matrix?

Tags: r, expression, bioconductor

I have two set data, 4 samples with 2 replicates for each one from batch 1  and another 4 samples with 2 replicates from batch 2.

I would like to remove batch effects from these samples and compare different methods together. 
I have done below commands but face with error:

```
design

                                 method batch
L4_rep1                               L    b1
L4_rep2                               L    b1
L6_L8_rep1                            L    b1
L6_L8_rep2                            L    b1
Q5_Q7_rep1                            Q    b1
Q5_Q7_rep2                            Q    b1
Q3_rep1                               Q    b1
Q3_rep2                               Q    b1
co_40d_A                          co_40d    b2
co_40d_B                          co_40d    b2
co_60d_A                          co_60d    b2
co_60d_B                          co_60d    b2
EB_A                                 EB    b2
EB_B                                 EB    b2
H9_A                                 H9    b2
H9_B                                 H9    b2


design$method <- factor(design$method, levels = c("L", "Q", "co_40d","co_60d", "EB", "H9"))
design$batch <- factor(design$batch, levels = c("b1", "b2"))

design.matrix <- model.matrix(~0+batch+method,design)

design.matrix

            batchb1 batchb2 methodQ methodco_40d methodco_60d methodEB methodH9
L4_rep1          1       0       0            0            0        0        0
L4_rep2          1       0       0            0            0        0        0
L6_L8_rep1       1       0       0            0            0        0        0
L6_L8_rep2       1       0       0            0            0        0        0
Q5_Q7_rep1       1       0       1            0            0        0        0
Q5_Q7_rep2       1       0       1            0            0        0        0
Q3_rep1          1       0       1            0            0        0        0
Q3_rep2          1       0       1            0            0        0        0
co_40d_A         0       1       0            1            0        0        0
co_40d_B         0       1       0            1            0        0        0
co_60d_A         0       1       0            0            1        0        0
co_60d_B         0       1       0            0            1        0        0
EB_A             0       1       0            0            0        1        0
EB_B             0       1       0            0            0        1        0
H9_A             0       1       0            0            0        0        1
H9_B             0       1       0            0            0        0        1

library(edgeR)
data_filter<- count table
edgeR.dgelist = DGEList(data_filter)
edgeR.dgelist_normal = calcNormFactors(edgeR.dgelist)
CommonDisp <- estimateGLMCommonDisp(edgeR.dgelist_normal, design.matrix)
Error in glmFit.default(y, design = design, dispersion = dispersion, offset = offset,  : Design matrix not of full rank.  The following coefficients not estimable: methodH9
```

I like to know whether my design matrix is correct?
Also, I like to compare Q method against other methods, would you please help me in making contrast?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create a full rank matrix based on this design.
If you have the value for the variable batch1 and one of the method columns, you can easily know the value of other dummies.
It is not possible to compare the methods across batches either, as e.g. there is no method "L" from batch 2 to compare with batch1.